# Dialog deforms when change the orientation Android

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, android-camera

I have an app that works with an activity to take pictures which works with landscape orientation, when take the picture and return to the activity (this activity works with portrait orientation) to validate the photo, the dialog deforms and change the orientation to horizontal

[This is the normal dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH13z.png)

[This is the dialog when deforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxXtu.png)

[This is the code for Dialog XML][3]

I change the orientation in the manifest, in the layout and programatically but nothing works.

Any other suggestion?

Code of dialog xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/loadingLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loadingImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_iso" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblLoading"
    android:layout_width="279dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loadingImg" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post the dialog xml

Comment: @javdromero Already posted

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @javdromero Sorry, I'm a kind of new asking here, I already post the code